# javascript errors on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have the following javascript errors on my site when I try to use http://phpchart.org/ to load a graph. Any idea how to fix these errors?
There could be a conflict somewhere. `http://testsitemg.com/ivn/email-subscription/`

```
jquery.jqplot.min.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uiBackCompat' of undefined
testsitemg.com/:423 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
showjs.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: c.curCSS is not a function
```

Comment: You are not including  the JS files in correct order

Comment: what should I do? I'm using the code from phpchart.org. I've just added require('phpChart/conf.php'); How do I change the order?

Comment: I am saying the order in which javascirpt file are getting including must not be correct

Comment: I don't get errors when using phpChart outside of wordpress. There must be a conflict somewhere. How do I resolve this. I can't change the order of the includes within the phpChart files.

Comment: First of all, compare all included and inlined JavaScript on the page with and without including phpChart. Any difference?

Comment: yes. There are 3 errors only connected to phpChart. They don't show otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this error you have to check few possibility as listed below.

1. First of all you have to check order of loading all js libraries that is loaded in you site. i.e jquery js should be loaded fist.
2. you have to whether all required js libries getting loaded or not. for this user developer tool and check it in network tab. and for detailed error check it in console tab where exactly error is occurring
3. In your site, check existing js libraries loaded,existing WordPress loaded script files getting conflicted with later loaded js files.
   So to avoid js libraries conflict, 
   Where ever you are using libraries file i.e `"jquery.jqplot.min.js /showjs.js /..."` etc. make sure before creating instance of library use

   $j = jQuery.noConflict();

for example: suppose you have to use plot js function then before using this 
make:

```
$myjplot = jQuery.noConflict();
$myjplot.jqplot('chartdiv',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);
```

I hope it would help to you.